# "awsmobile init" is not working for web react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I was following the steps given in the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/web-getting-started.html).

But after creating hello-world react app, I went into app root folder and tried to run "awsmobile init" command but I got error 'Unexpected token function'.

I am using node version v6.11.5

My question is why am I getting this error as there is no reference to this error given in the documentation ? How to resolve it ?

Comment: I have also take reference from "https://github.com/aws/awsmobile-cli/issues/120" but according to them version upgrade will resolve the issue.

Comment: But i have other projects also in my laptop which are built using old version of node js. Will up-gradation of node version will cause any issue for those project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use node version 7 and above, the awsmobile-cli has been tested extensively on node version 8.9.x
The error you reported here seems to be caused by old version of node is not able to parse newer js features.